# How to scrape an image that's stored in an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I am trying to add src to an img tag in electron and it just returns an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()

Running the same img tag in a browser shows the src image correctly.

The src is : https://novelplanet.com/Uploads/I-Might-Be-A-Fake-Cultivator848.jpg

- The img tag:

```
<img 
    id="chapter"
    class="novelCover"
    src="https://novelplanet.com/Uploads/I-Might-Be-A-Fake-Cultivator848.jpg"
    border="0"
    alt=""
/>
```

- CSS just in case:

```
.novelCover {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5% 5% 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

503 Error is "Service Unavailable". You're running into one of two issues

- Your electron app is unable to satisfy Cloudflare anti-bot protection.
- The website may be blocking your request by User Agent.

Try opening your URL in "Incognito" mode and pay attention to the load process. Instead of an image you're getting the page that pops up and displays a notice about DDoS Protection.

Comment: yes, it seems like cloudflare is preventing me from accessing the file. when downloading the file, it returns its html page. Anyway I could possibly download this img from js or python. I am using a cloudflare-bypasser but it seems to only work for html content.

Comment: electron is for a user interface right? You want to open up a page there such that you can get the cookies set, and then use those cookies when you do your request. Keep in mind that if the website doesn't like what you're doing, they have every right to make things more difficult later...